# How to generate all graphs on $n$ vertices including a given subgraph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I'm working on a graph theory problem and as an intermediate step I need to draw all the simple graphs on $n$ vertices including a given subgraph, is there an algorithm to make sure I can generate all of them without repetition (up to isomorphism) or missing one of them?

Comment: This seems very relevant: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29552/enumerate-all-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-a-certain-size

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Jorge Fernández. I'd like to do some counting and analyzing the properties of graphs containing the specific subgraph/substructure.

Comment: @Andrey Portnoy. Thanks! But I'd like to generate all graphs containing the specific substructure.

Comment: **All** the simple graphs on $n$ vertices? You realize that there are quite, quite, many of them for general $n$, right?

Comment: @Mike. Yes. But I only consider the graphs for small $n$, like $n \le 20$.

Comment: This problem will scale very poorly with n. Here's the sequence of the number of graph isomorphism classes http://oeis.org/A000088 .